# $x+\alpha y$ for $\alpha \geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha$ is a scalar then we know that $x+\alpha y$ is a straight line.

What can we say when $\alpha \geq 0$?

I know a concept called a cone. Is the set $x+\alpha y$ for $\alpha \geq 0$ a cone?

Comment: It is called a 'ray'.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{ x + \alpha y \mid \alpha \ge 0 \}$ is indeed a cone, but as @KaviRamaMurthy observes, it's also called "the ray from $x$ in direction $y$."